# IDictionary<TKey, TValue> implementation and contract for replacing values

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a "contract" for the interface `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` I should follow when implementing value replacement with `this[key] = newValue`? An example:

```
IDictionary<MyKey, string> dict = CreateEmptyDict();
var k1 = new MyKey(123);
var k2 = new MyKey(123);  
dict.Add(k1, "foo");
dict[k2] = "bar";
```

k1 and k2 are such that `k1.Equals(k2)` and they have the same hash code, but they are reference types so `ReferenceEquals(k1, k2) == false`.

The BCL `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` will contain `(k1, "bar")`.
My question is: is this a "contract" I really should follow for any implementation of `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` or can I let my implementation contain `(k2, "bar")` if it is easier to do so in the underlying data structure?

Comment: if you are unsure, you can always look at the [reference implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's implementation-specific at least to *some* extent. For example, `Dictionary<,>` allows you to specify an `IEqualityComparer<T>` to use to check keys for equality, and `SortedDictionary<,>` doesn't use `Equals` and `GetHashCode` at all - instead, it uses `IComparer<T>` to check for key *ordering*.

It would be entirely reasonable to create a dictionary which relied on *solely* reference equality - but make sure you document that very carefully. I would note that you don't really need to implement `IDictionary<,>` yourself to do that... you just need to use `Dictionary<,>` and custom equality comparer which uses reference equality and [`RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11tbk3h9(v=vs.110).aspx) to fetch the hash code that `Object.GetHashCode()` would use if it weren't overridden.

It would be very, very weird for a dictionary to be implemented so that you could add the exact *same* value as a key multiple times - but how you judge whether keys are actually equal is a different matter, IMO.

Comment: Should it be `IEqualityComparer<T>` instead of `EqualityComparer<T>`?

Comment: @PetSerAl: Fixed, thanks. Distracted by answering a question on stage at a conference :)

Comment: Thanks, yes I use no hashes at all. The underlying structure to my dict is a tree structure in which it's easier to insert a new kvp, than to modify an existing one (unlike a hash table where updating a value for a key is easy). So in the most straightforward impl I will get (k2, v2) rather than the (k1, v2) of the BCL dict.

Comment: @AndersForsgren: A tree suggests that you're comparing the keys by ordering... at which point, wouldn't the two equal keys sort equally anyway?

Comment: The underlying tree is a quadtree of sorts, so no real ordering exists. Example `k1 = {"a", 1, 2}` and `k2 = {"b", 1, 2}` and an equality comparer for the dict that looks only at the grid coordinate 1,2 will replace the value and has to decide whether to keep key `k1` or `k2` for that value.

Comment: @AndersForsgren: Okay, so equivalent to just a custom equality operator, basically?

Comment: Basically, yes. The complication is wrapping IDictionary around something that doesn't satisfy a triangle (in)equality. If you allow distances in the 2D space, then you can have "distinct" keys a and c, and when you insert a point b between them you must remove both before inserting the new entry, since b==a and b==c but a!=c.

Comment: @AndersForsgren: Okay - I would strongly try to avoid violating that if at all possible.

Comment: It's possible - by simply removing the IDictionary interface :). But it's internal code and not a public API and it's for replacing something worse (using the normal Dictionary<K,V> with non triangle inequality hashes - which is terrible). This is at worst surprising.